# How do I structure a SQL query to find an object that is the parent of two specific other objects?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

Say I have 2 tables, called parent and child. A parent can have zero to many children, and a child can have 1 to many parents. How do I find all the parent elements that are parents of two specific children.

For instance, say I have Parents [p_a, p_b, p_c, p_d], and children: [c_a, c_b]
They have a structure as follows:

- p_a has c_a as a child
- p_b has c_b as a child
- p_c has both c_a and c_b as children
- p_d has no children

How do I formulate a query to select p_c?

If they had a structure where p has [id, name] and c has [id, name] and there is a join_table with [parent_id, child_id]. (I have also given them sequential id's for this example to make things easier).

My attempt to solve it came up with the following SQL

```
SELECT p.*
FROM parent AS p
JOIN join_table AS j ON p.id = j.parent_id
JOIN children AS c ON j.child_id = c.id
WHERE c = 1
  OR c = 2
```

But obviously this selects p_a and p_b as well as p_c. I've been looking at the [UNION](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) operator but can't seem to get it working.

Looking forward to your answers, thanks for reading.
mike

EDIT: mentioned the id convention I'm using for the example

Comment: in your example c_a has id=1, and c_b id=2 ?

Comment: @GrzegorzMotyl Sorry yes, that's the convention I'm using, just realised I didn't specify them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to the accepted answer, probably faster:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM parent p JOIN join_table j ON p.id=j.parent_id
WHERE j.child_id=1 OR j.child_id=2
GROUP BY j.parent_id
HAVING COUNT(j.child_id)=2;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you have solved this specific example, unfortunately I was looking for a more general method to be used with a variable number of arguments. My fault, I should have been more clear. Thanks for your effort. (And obviously +1 for optimising for the case I gave)

Comment: I would argue that this is more general than the accepted answer. Not in code - you would still need to alter both queries in similar ways - but in efficiency. Regardless of how many children you want as arguments, this query will always yield one join and one linear-time filtering of where conditions. The same cannot (without deeper knowledge of the DB's optimization algorithms) be said for the accepted answer where an additional child could add an order of complexity (n^2, n^3, n^4 and so on).

Comment: Sure good point, but when there are children c_a, c_b and c_c and we only want c_a and c_b (exactly) I don't think this would work, as if there were c_a and c_c, that would still pass the query (please correct me if I'm wrong). (Me not specifying that requirement was what I said I made a mistake in not being clear enough about).

Comment: No, because of the where clause, lines with c_c wouldn't be included.

Comment: ahhh... I think you're right. not sure I'd grokked that completely... Thanks, I feel like this would really speed things up.

Comment: This is a good solution and probably faster than my suggestion. I tend to advice the straight-forward method first. So when one looks for parents where two child records exist and doesn't even think of the EXISTS clause than it's time to learn to look for such signal words and create the query accordingly. Optimizing is the next step. And yes, I would prefer niklon's answer then. As to showing both child names, Mike H-R, use niklon's query, join the children table and add group_concat(children.name).

Comment: Just a side note: I would group by p.id in spite of it having the same value as j.parent_id, just to make it cristal clear, that I group by parent's key. Just for readability. I would also count(\*), because I count records rather than records where j.child_id is not null (which is always the case). Also just for readability. (Counting all non-null values rather than just records *could* be slower, but I guess that a modern dbms such as MySQL optimizes the query internally such that it notices about the redundancy and simply counts records anyway.)

Comment: Good point @ThorstenKettner. Straight-forward is the way to start. I wasn't looking to get the accepted answer here, though I definitely wanted upvotes :). As scalability is often a concern with databases, I felt this alternative was needed.

Comment: ah, group_concat, awesome! thank you @ThorstenKettner, and of course thank you niklon as well.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner and niklon. I had thought that these approaches were equivalent but have found a situation where they do not appear to be (I was trying to combine them which may have lead to the problem), could you have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23359790/can-anyone-explain-why-this-first-sql-query-gives-0-when-this-second-query-gives) and see what I might be missing? thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for parents where two specific child records exist. Use the EXISTS clause for that:

```
SELECT *
FROM parent p
WHERE EXISTS (select * from join_table j where j.parent_id = p.id and j.child_id = 1)
  AND EXISTS (select * from join_table j where j.parent_id = p.id and j.child_id = 2);
```

Comment: exactly the kind of thing I was looking for, thank you Thorsten.

Comment: quick question, is it possible to keep the joins in the outer body (as in after parent p). While typing this I think I'm realising that you can't do that because then it will still have the same problems my original query has. Gonna post anyway for confirmation that I'm understanding it right (and that the joins must be "a child" of the exists)

Comment: You would join with the parent table when you wanted to show the children with their parents. Then you would have to consider, what you actually want to see in your result list. One record with p_c and ca and another with pc and c_b? Or just one record for p_c and some aggregation on the children (say the average age or a string containing both their names or something). You would join inside the exists clauses when you wanted to find the children by some criteria in the children table.

Comment: Thank you, you couldn't point me to a resource where I could read about how one might go about creating a string containing both of the names could you? (links to docs is fine, I just didn't know of a function that could do that! I get the feeling I should learn about it.)

Comment: MySQL has GROUP_CONCAT for that. Use niklon's query plus a join to the children table with it. Here is a link on MySQL's aggregate functions: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html