# How do I get the count for a SQL query containing a GROUP BY statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

So I have a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM parent p JOIN join_table j ON p.id=j.parent_id
WHERE j.child_id=1 OR j.child_id=2
GROUP BY j.parent_id
HAVING COUNT(j.child_id)=2;
```

Which I got from [this excellent answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23126518/how-do-i-structure-a-sql-query-to-find-an-object-that-is-the-parent-of-two-speci). Now I would like to modify the query to return the count of all the parent elements there. unfortunately due to the `GROUP BY` statement I am unable to do this (as it will give the count of each grouped statement).

My attempt was the obvious and naive approach:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(p.id))
FROM parent p JOIN join_table j ON p.id=j.parent_id
WHERE j.child_id=1 OR j.child_id=2
GROUP BY j.parent_id
HAVING COUNT(j.child_id)=2;
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Would you output the result by running your second query ?

Comment: Sorry, can't believe I missed that, the result is the counts grouped by the j.parent_id (which makes sense as it is what is being queried) this is however not what I was trying to query for but merely my best guess at the form of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
   (SELECT p.*
   FROM parent p JOIN join_table j ON p.id=j.parent_id
   WHERE j.child_id=1 OR j.child_id=2
   GROUP BY j.parent_id
   HAVING COUNT(j.child_id)=2) AS res;
```

Comment: Try again. I missed the alias of the sub query :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(CN) FROM (    
  SELECT p.*, count(*) cn
  FROM parent p JOIN join_table j ON p.id=j.parent_id
  WHERE j.child_id=1 OR j.child_id=2
  GROUP BY j.parent_id
  HAVING COUNT(j.child_id)=2
);
```

This should give you the total count